# Storing and Retrieving postgres nested JSONB data type in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, forms, postgresql, jsonb

I realised there is not much information about how to use rails form to store and retrieve JSON type data. I am currently facing the following problem:

I have a form that creates a nested structure in JSON:

```
= form_for(@car) do |cf|
    = cf.fields_for :locations do | locations_f |
        = locations_f.fields_for :primary_location do | primary_location_f |
            .sm-col.md-col.sm-col-6.px2
                label.inline-block.mb1 District
                = primary_location_f.text_field :district 
            .sm-col.md-col.sm-col-6.px2
                label.inline-block.mb1 Street
                = primary_location_f.text_field :street
```

It will generate input HTML tags as such:

`<input name="car[locations][primary_location][district]">`

`<input name="car[locations][primary_location][street]">`

I am able to persist it in database after doing `params.permit`:

```
params.require(:car).permit([
    locations:[primary_location:[:street, :district]]
])
```

I also create `store_accessor` in the model

```
store_accessor :locations, :primary_location, :other_locations
```

However, after I persisted the data, I want it to be shown in the `text_field` what is already persisted in the database. I try to do something like:

```
= primary_location_f.text_field :district, value: @car.locations['primary_location']['district']
```

However, it will run into NilClass Error as sometimes `@car.locations['primary_location']` may be nil, and error will arise when I call `@car.locations['primary_location']['district']`.

I wonder what is the best way to store and retrieve JSON data type. And what is a good way when the JSON is nested.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> However, it will run into NilClass Error as sometimes @car.locations['primary_location'] may be nil, and error will arise when I call @car.locations['primary_location']['district'].

Use [`.try()`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Object.html#method-i-try) method.

```
@car.locations.try(:[],:primary_location).try(:[], :district)
```

> I wonder what is the best way to store and retrieve JSON data type. And what is a good way when the JSON is nested.

I prefer built in JSON `store`. Similar to what you are using.

Comment: Hi how would you use store to achieve it? How can it retrieve the data to the form?

Comment: The form simply calls accessors to your fields, so just add corresponding `store_accessor`s. As for json with levels deeper than 1 I would write loops in the view.

Comment: Thanks. Will you be able to write an example to help me understand better? Thanks!